# "In" iterability issue

Tags: python, pandas

This is super basic, but I could use a hand.

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
   name     yes      no
0  'a'     ('b',)
1  'b'     ('a',)
2  'c'              ('a', 'b')
```

And I'm trying to score the data like this:

```
def score(x):
    if x[0] in x[1] == True:   
        return 1
    if x[0] in x[2] == True:  
        return 0
    else:
        []

sh['label']= sh.apply(score, axis=1)
```

On the second if statement, but not the first, I get this error

```
TypeError: ("argument of type 'float' is not iterable", 'occurred at index 1')
```

It seems like it doesn't have a problem with the tuple with one item, but doesn't like the tuple with two.

How can I fix it?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Why `== True`?...

Comment: `x` probably doesn't contain what you expect. Put `print(x[2])` before the second `if`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is with `NaN`, so one possible solution is [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) by some value not in column `name` first:

```
#if need select by position use iloc
def score(x):
    print (x)
    if x.iloc[0] in x.iloc[1]:   
        return 1
    elif x.iloc[0] in x.iloc[2]:  
        return 0

sh['label']= sh.fillna('tmp').apply(score, axis=1)

print(sh)
```

---

```
#if need select by column name
def score(x):
    #print (x)
    if x['name'] in x['yes']:   
        return 1
    elif x['name'] in x['no']:  
        return 0


sh['label']= sh.fillna('tmp').apply(score, axis=1)
print(sh)
```

Sample:

```
sh = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['b','b','b'],
    'yes': [('b',),('a',),np.nan],
    'no':[np.nan, np.nan, ('a','b')]        
})
print(sh)
  name      no   yes
0    b     NaN  (b,)
1    b     NaN  (a,)
2    b  (a, b)   NaN

def score(x):
    #print (x)
    if x['name'] in x['yes']:   
        return 1
    elif x['name'] in x['no']:  
        return 0

sh['label']= sh.fillna('tmp').apply(score, axis=1)
print(sh)
  name      no   yes  label
0    b     NaN  (b,)    1.0
1    b     NaN  (a,)    NaN
2    b  (a, b)   NaN    0.0
```

But problem with code above is if value is in both columns `yes` and `no`. One possible solution is create `2` new columns with `boolean` `True` and `False` and then cast to `int` (`1`, `0`) by `astype`:

```
sh = pd.DataFrame({
    'name': ['b','b','b'],
    'yes': [('b',),('a',),np.nan],
    'no':[np.nan, ('b',), ('a','b')]        
})
print(sh)
  name      no   yes
0    b     NaN  (b,)
1    b    (b,)  (a,)
2    b  (a, b)   NaN

sh['label-yes']= sh.fillna('tmp').apply(lambda x: x['name'] in x['yes'], axis=1)
sh['label-no']= sh.fillna('tmp').apply(lambda x: x['name'] in x['no'], axis=1)
sh[['label-yes', 'label-no']] = sh[['label-yes', 'label-no']].astype(int)
print(sh)
  name      no   yes  label-yes  label-no
0    b     NaN  (b,)          1         0
1    b    (b,)  (a,)          0         1
2    b  (a, b)   NaN          0         1
```